# Grunt, Cordova & Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, gruntjs

I am developing an app for multiple platforms using Cordova. Grunt is used as a build tool. I use it to copy my source code to the right folder for each platform so I can develop them independently.

This works fine with Android using the scripts that are provided by Cordova. However, I have no idea if or how it is possible to automate the WP build process. I'm looking for two things:

1. Add all files in the `www` directory to the VS project (it does not include files that are not added to the project, which is sad).
2. Build, install and run the app in the emulator. I used adb & Grunt's exec for Android which was really simple, is there something similar for WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [recent commit](https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp7/commit/fa0662a82f68bcf946ed7a14c065d540a5804f7e) now makes it possible to use www\** in the .csproj file, which solved my first issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in a cordova windows phone project there is a directory called 'cordova' which contains scripts to do all of this.

There should be scripts to build and run your project.

The run script can pretty much do it all. You can call it like :

`run --device --release`
or

`run --emulator --debug`
or just
`run`